# Why do SimpleJdbcCall igronre @Transactional annotation

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-jdbc, spring-transactions

I want to do some DB related actions in service method. Initialy it looks like this:

```
@Override
@Transactional
public void addDirectory(Directory directory) {
    //some cheks here
    directoryRepo.save(directory);
    rsdhUtilsService.createPhysTable(directory);
}
```

Firs method `directoryRepo.save(directory);` is just simple JPA save action, second one `rsdhUtilsService.createPhysTable(directory);` is `JDBCTemplate` stored procedure call from it's own service. The problem is: if any exceptions accures within JPA or SimpleJdbcCall action, transaction will rollback and nothig related to JPA won't be persited, but if exception occures **only** within JPA action, result of SimpleJdbcCall won't be affected by transaction rollback.
To illustrate this behaviour I've remove JAP action, mark `@Transactional` as `(readOnly = true)` and moved all `JDBCTemplate` related logic from another service to current one.

```
@Service
public class DirectoriesServiceImpl implements DirectoriesService {

    private final DirectoryRepo directoryRepo;

    private final MapSQLParamUtils sqlParamUtils;

    private final JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @Autowired
    public DirectoriesServiceImpl(DirectoryRepo directoryRepo, MapSQLParamUtils sqlParamUtils, JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
        this.directoryRepo = directoryRepo;
        this.sqlParamUtils = sqlParamUtils;
        this.jdbcTemplate = jdbcTemplate;
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public void addDirectory(Directory directory) {
        directoryRepo.save(directory);

        new SimpleJdbcCall(jdbcTemplate).withSchemaName("RSDH_DICT").withCatalogName("UTL_DICT")
                .withFunctionName("create_dict")
                .executeFunction(String.class, sqlParamUtils.getMapSqlParamForCreatePhysTable(directory));
    }

}
```

As a result `@Transactional` annotation is ignored and I can see new records persisted in DB.
I've got only one DataSource configured via `application.properties`, and here is how `JDBCTemlate` configured

```
@Component
class MapSQLParamUtils {

    private final DataSource dataSource;

    @Autowired
    MapSQLParamUtils(DataSource dataSource) {
        this.dataSource = dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate() {
        return new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }

}
```

So my questions are: why do `@Transactional` ignored by `SimpleJdbcCall` and how to configure `JPA` and `JDBCTemlate` to use same transaction manager.

**UPDATE**:
This is how I use this service in controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/v1/directories")
public class DirectoriesRESTControllerV1 {

    private final DirectoriesService directoriesService;

    @Autowired
    public DirectoriesRESTControllerV1(DirectoriesService directoriesService) {
        this.directoriesService = directoriesService;
    }

    @PostMapping
    @PreAuthorize("hasPermission('DIRECTORIES_USER', 'W')")
    public ResponseEntity createDirectory(@NotNull @RequestBody DirectoryRequestDTO createDirectoryRequestDTO) {
        Directory directoryFromRequest = ServiceUtils.convertDtoToEntity(createDirectoryRequestDTO);
        directoriesService.addDirectory(directoryFromRequest);
        return ResponseEntity.noContent().build();
    }

}
```

Comment: Please show the code where you call `addDirectory`.

Comment: @chrylis I've update my question

Comment: No time to read and participate, but a bell rang: JPA might not always be combined with JDBC, depending on the JPA caching.

Comment: @chrylis, @vipul tnx, but I guess I've found the cause. I guess it' because of what exactly `withFunctionName("create_dict")` does. We are using Oracle as our DB, so `create_dict` function creates a DB table and this action can not be rolled back one's it's done. If I use `@Transactional ` all actions within seems to behave async, thus while `directoryRepo.save(directory)` starts, programm goes futher and executes `rsdhUtilsService.createPhysTable(directory)` without waiting for result of previous method call, and if it's brakes, result of `createPhysTable(directory)` can not be rolled back

Answer (score 1):

1. As mentioned earlier, the problem here is that JPA does not execute sql queries at once repository methods called. To enforce it you can use explicit `entityManager.flush()`:

```java
@Autowired
private javax.persistence.EntityManager entityManager;
...

@Override
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public void addDirectory(Directory directory) {
    directoryRepo.save(directory);
    entityManager.flush();

    new SimpleJdbcCall(jdbcTemplate).withSchemaName("RSDH_DICT").withCatalogName("UTL_DICT")
            .withFunctionName("create_dict")
            .executeFunction(String.class, sqlParamUtils.getMapSqlParamForCreatePhysTable(directory));
}
```

2. To see real SQL queries by hibernate you can enable option `show_sql`, in case if your application is spring-boot, this configuration enables it:

```
spring.jpa:
  show-sql: true
  properties:
    hibernate:
      format_sql: true

logging.level:
  org.hibernate.SQL: DEBUG
```

3. Regarding transaction manager. In case if entityManager flush is not enough, you may need the composite transaction manager, that handles both JPA and DataSource. Spring data commons has [ChainedTransactionManager](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-commons/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/transaction/ChainedTransactionManager.java). Note: you should be careful with it. I used it this way in my project:

```java
    @Bean(BEAN_CONTROLLER_TX)
    public PlatformTransactionManager controllerTransactionManager(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory);
    }

    @Bean(BEAN_ANALYTICS_TX)
    public PlatformTransactionManager analyticsTransactionManager(DataSource dataSource) {
        return new DataSourceTransactionManager(dataSource);
    }

    /**
     * Chained both 2 transaction managers.
     *
     * @return chained transaction manager for controller datasource and analytics datasource
     */
    @Primary
    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(
            @Qualifier(BEAN_CONTROLLER_TX) PlatformTransactionManager controllerTransactionManager,
            @Qualifier(BEAN_ANALYTICS_TX) PlatformTransactionManager analyticsTransactionManager) {
        return new ChainedTransactionManager(controllerTransactionManager, analyticsTransactionManager);
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Please try this :

```
@Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)
public void addDirectory(Directory directory){
```

@Transactional only rolls back transactions for unchecked exceptions. For checked exceptions and their subclasses, it commits data. So although an exception is raised here, because it's a checked exception, Spring ignores it and commits the data to the database.

So if you throw an Exception or a subclass of it, always use the above with the @Transactional annotation to tell Spring to roll back transactions if a checked exception occurs.

It's very simple, just use the following with @Transactional:

```
@Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)
```

Comment: The code in the question doesn't throw checked exceptions.